# post form to same site

Tags: javascript, html

Do you know how to post the form to the same site where the form is?

This does not work:

```
<form action="window.location.href();" method="post">...</form>
```

Comment: You can't use POST method for static `.html` pages - it's by design behavior. If you have mix of `.html` and of server side pages like `.aspx` or `.php` there is JS workaround - the JS code would check the page extension and decide what method to use - just let me know if relevant.

Comment: It is PHP (that uses template).

Comment: Then `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` is your friend!

Comment: It's not my friend because I use smarty template :(

Comment: Another friend: `action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty `action`

```
<form method="post">...</form>
```

works!

http://binarious.de/sandbox/post.php

or with PHP

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"
```

or with Smarty

```
action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}"
```

Comment: Sorry, it's doing that only when the page is `.html`

Comment: How can you **post** to a static file? When you POST to a static file every web server should (correctly) respond with 405 which in this case means something like "What should I do with the parameters? It's a static file!"

Comment: How do you know that he's acting with static files? Futhermore he just asked how to post to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Just render the absolute or relative URL in `action`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

> **Action attribute**
>
> Where to send the form data. Possible values:
>
> An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
>   action="http://www.example.com/example.htm") A relative URL - points
>   to a file within a web site (like action="example.htm")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot literally put JavaScript in HTML except for events.

Instead, set it dynamically through JavaScript:

```
document.forms[0].action = window.location.href;
```

Comment: also `onsubmit="this.action=window.location.href"` should do the job.